# devtools "Compositing mode is not supported"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, frame-rate

When trying to activate the rendering options on either chromium (33.0.1750.152 (Developer Build 256984) Ubuntu 13.10) or chrome (34.0.1847.116 (Official Build 260972) ) I get these errors:

```
Error applying setting showDebugBorders: Compositing mode is not supported
Error applying setting showFPSCounter: Compositing mode is not supported
Error applying setting continuousPainting: Compositing mode is not supported
Error applying setting showScrollBottleneckRects: Compositing mode is not supported
```

I tried activating some flags but that didn't help. How can I get the FPS counter to work?

Comment: It looks like you're running with accelerated compositing disabled, please check about:gpu page.

Comment: it says "Hardware acceleration unavailable" is there anything I can do? Update the drivers or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with the default drivers from my chip.
Installing drivers from the Intel website seem to have fixed the issue.